# Porcentagem de acerto Machine Learning utilizando sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, sklearn

Estava estudando algumas coisas em Machine Learning, e encontrei o seguinte codigo:

https://github.com/dadosaocubo/nlp/blob/master/NLP_com_scikit_learn.ipynb

Na minha máquina rodou certinho, porém tenho uma dúvida. Nessa parte do código:

```
itens = ['FEIJÃO','AÇÚCAR','QUEIJO']
for item in itens:
    print('Produto:', item, 'Departamento:', novo_item(item))

Produto: FEIJÃO Departamento: MERCEARIA SALGADA
Produto: AÇUCAR Departamento: MERCEARIA DOCE
Produto: QUEIJO Departamento: FRIOS
```

Como eu faço pra recuperar a porcentagem de certeza que a maquina tem que o produto pertence ao departamento? Por exemplo, gostaria que o retorno fosse:

```
Produto: FEIJÃO Departamento: MERCEARIA SALGADA COM 95% DE CERTEZA
Produto: AÇUCAR Departamento: MERCEARIA DOCE COM 84% DE CERTEZA
Produto: QUEIJO Departamento: FRIOS COM 45% DE CERTEZA
```

Pois quero criar uma métrica, se for acima de 90% de certeza, trazer o departamento. Se for menos que isso, trazer a informação DEPARTAMENTO NÃO LOCALIZADO COM CERTEZA.
Como fazer algo nesse tipo?

Comment: No "notebook" do link de seu post, vc já possui uma tabela com _precision_, _recall_ e _f1-score_. O que você está querendo exatamente?

Comment: Isso, mas eu quero saber a precisão de acerto de um item novo, que não esteja na tabela já cadastrada. Se eu adicionar o item "PRODUTO NOVO TESTE", quero saber a porcentagem de certeza que eu tenho que a categoria correta foi encontrada.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Por natureza, regressão linear **não** possui probabilidade de acerto. Isso se dá porque este modelo tenta representar seus dados em uma linha reta. Existem algumas métricas como "Root Mean Square Error (RMSE)", mas não acho que seja o que você procura.

Acredito que outro método como o DecisionTree ou RandomForest funcionaria melhor para seu caso.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

### Importando bibliotecas

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import metrics
```

### Criando dados falsos

```
x = np.array([i for i in range(100)]).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.array([random.choice(["Area 1", "Area 2", "Area 3"]) for _ in range(100)])
```

### Gerando modelo

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier()

clf.fit(x, y)
```

### Fazendo predição

```
clf.predict(np.array(200).reshape(-1, 1))

# O output será algo como
# array(['Area 2'], dtype='<U6')
```

### Checando probabilidades

```
clf.predict_proba(np.array(200).reshape(-1, 1))

# A resposta será como
# array([[0.25, 0.72, 0.03]])
# Ou seja 25% para Área 1, 72% para Área 2 e 3% para Área 3
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu precisava. Só complementando, eu consigo alguma forma de identificar cada porcentagem no array? Ou seja, saber que o 0.25 representa a Area 1, e assim por diante?

Comment: Veja que ao definir o `y` a ordem é "Área 1", depois "Área 2"... Você pode fazer um [`zip`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp) desta lista com a de resultados.

Comment: Para quem votou negativo, pode informar o motivo para que eu melhore a resposta?

Comment: @zanonale, caso ache pertinente, favor marcar a resposta como aceita.